# Copy and paste text between sheets with VBA code if a condition is true

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets on a Excel workbook :

- in the first sheet I have numbers of purchasing orders in range C and sometimes there is a comment related to the purchasing order in range B
- in the second sheet, I have also purchasing orders in range C (PO) with comments in range C.

Some PO are the same between the sheets. I would like to copy the comment from the 2nd sheet to the first one if the PO is the same with VBA.

In short: if PO Sheets1 = PO sheets2 so copy comment of sheets2 into sheets 1

I have looked on different topics and have tested different codes but I am a beginner in VBA so I need help.

I can copy the last code I tested found and tailored on another topic but it does not work:

```
 Sub copycomment()

Dim i As Long
Dim col1 As Long
Dim col2 As Long
Dim sheetOne As String
Dim sheetTwo As String


col1 = 3
col2 = 3
sheetOne = "Feuil1"
sheetTwo = "Feuil2"
lastrow1 = Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(Sheets(sheetOne).Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(Sheets(sheetTwo).Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 2 To lastrow2

            If Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, col1).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, col2).Value Then
            Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, 2).Value

       End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

I hope I am clear
Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try This code if this matches your requirement.

```
Sub copycomment()

Dim i As Long
Dim col1 As Long
Dim col2 As Long
Dim sheetOne As String
Dim sheetTwo As String


col1 = 3
col2 = 3
sheetOne = "Feuil1"
sheetTwo = "Feuil2"
lastrow1 = Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(Sheets(sheetOne).Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(Sheets(sheetTwo).Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 2 To lastrow2

            If Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, col1).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, col2).Value Then
            Sheets(sheetOne).Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheets(sheetTwo).Cells(j, 2).Comment.Text 'Copies comment from sheettwo to sheetone
            Exit For
            End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```